# Primefaces Tree - nó não é selecionado com o botão direito

Tags: primefaces

Migrei para a versão 5.1 do Primefaces e agora quando clico com o botão direito para abrir o ContextMenu o **nó não é selecionado**. Na versão 5.0 funcionava corretamente.

```
<h:form>
  <p:tree id="plano" value="#{planoMB.plano}" var="p" selectionMode="single" selection="#{planoMB.selectedNode}">
    <p:treeNode type="movto" icon="ui-icon-document">
      <h:outputText value="#{p.descricao}" />
    </p:treeNode>
  </p:tree>
  <p:contextMenu>
    <p:menuitem value="Editar" update=":editPlano" oncomplete="PF('dlgEditPlano').show()"/>
  </p:contextMenu>                    
</h:form>
```

Comment: Este tipo de regressão/mudança é comum entre as versões do PrimeFaces. Já tive problemas semelhantes e a solução foi analisar o código original em JavaScript, comparando as mudanças entre as versões, até encontrar o ponto que afetava o comportamento específico. Tente postar esse problema no fórum oficial do PF, mas nem sempre eles dão qualquer atenção por lá.

Comment: Pois é, já postei no fórum oficial, mas pelo jeito serei forçado a assinar a versão Elite, pois pelo menos assim eu poderei ter a versão mais atual.

Comment: Dá pra pegar o trunk do SVN deles e compilar na sua máquina pra ver se funciona primeiro. Não é tão complicado pois os projetos usam Maven.

Comment: Sim, comecei a fazer isso ontem, porém, acho que a versão que está no SVN não é a estável, já que algumas classes estão com erro... vou ver o que dá pra fazer. ;)

Comment: Realmente pode ser um problema usar o trunk. O SVN deles não está com as tags das releases?

Comment: Ops! Burrice minha. Procurei no BRANCHE e esqueci do TAG :D Lá estão todas as releases community sim. Agora é trabalhar no bug. Valeu!